# Падает билд приложения на React, Vite. Используем Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: reactjs, svg, импорт, vite

При билде приложения вылетает подобная ошибка:

```
0.401 yarn run v1.22.19
0.426 $ vite build
0.641 vite v4.5.1 building for production...
0.673 transforming...
3.732 ✓ 868 modules transformed.
3.733 ✓ built in 3.09s
3.733 Could not resolve "./location.svg" from "src/shared/svg/16px/icons.jsx"
3.733 file: /app/src/shared/svg/16px/icons.jsx
3.735 error during build:
3.735 RollupError: Could not resolve "./location.svg" from "src/shared/svg/16px/icons.jsx           "
3.735     at error (file:///app/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30)
3.735     at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///app/node_modules/rollup/dist/e           s/shared/node-entry.js:24860:24)
3.735     at file:///app/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24822:26
3.762 error Command failed with exit code 1.
3.762 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

Конфиг стандартный, для импорта svg как ReactComponent использую svgr:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import svgr from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react(), svgr()],

});
```

Не понимаю в чем ошибка, потому что при запуске на localhost все работает корректно.
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: в svgr вроде синтексис изменился. Терь что то типо такого 'import Logo from 'path/logo.svg?react'', чисто предположение поскольку исходников нету. Детальнее тут: https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/19282